# Visualizar las tareas por realizar a partir del dia de hoy ,rango de hora 18:00 a 8:00 del siguiente día mediante JQL Jira utilizando startOfDay()

Tags: jira, jql

trabajando con Jira por medio de Jql,

Trato de obtener todas las tareas que fueron creadas a partir de un rango de horas de 18:00 a 8:00 del siguiente dia.

Esta instrucción es la que estoy realizando

```
project = "prueba" AND (created >='2022-02-10 8:00' AND created <= '2022-02-10 18:00' OR created >= '2022-02-11 8:00' AND created <='2022-02-11 18:00')
```

Al ejecutar el query obtengo los ticket creados del día de hoy y las de ayer, como puedo validar solo los rangos de hora con `startOfDay()` ?

Comment: Buscas hoy las tareas que se crearon mañana? O_o

Comment: Mientras no quede clara la relación entre el JQL que pones acá y lo que realmente quieres buscar, es imposible darte una equivalencia que funcione

Answer (score 0):

El camino siempre debería comenzar por revisar la [documentación](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/advanced-search-reference-jql-functions/#Advancedsearchingfunctionsreference-startOfDay).

Dependiendo de si [configuraste Hours per day](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/configuring-time-tracking-861253946.html) en 8 horas o algo así (menos de 24), tienes que definir un

```
startOfDay("-2h")
```

Si *Hours per day* está en 8, o

```
startOfDay("-14h")
```

Si *Hours per day* está en 24.

Así pues, una forma simple de traducir tu búsqueda sin lidiar con horas sería:

```
project = "prueba" AND (
    (created >= startOfDay("-1d") AND created <= endOfDay("-1d")) 
    OR 
    (created >= startOfDay() AND created <= endOfDay()) 
)
```

Y de hecho, me pregunto si necesitas los dos intervalos o si con sólo hacer `created >= startOfDay("-1d") AND created <= endOfDay()`, basta

PD. También se puede usar `startOfDay("-2w")` para semanas, `startOfDay("-26m")` para minutos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: De echo si necesitaria 2 intervalos ya que necesito sacar los ticket que entraran hoy a las 18:00 hasta los ticket que entran mañana a las 8:00 esos son los rangos de hora , como podria implementarlo?

Comment: Si la respuesta no te resolvió, no la marques aceptada. Ese tick es para que todos sepan que hay una solución a tu pregunta. Y sobre lo que me dices, cómo se supone que hoy a las 18:00 busque lo que se crea mañana a las 8:00? No es al revés? Mañana a las 8:00 busco lo que se creó desde las 18:00 del día anterior. Igual, sigo sin entender cómo es que, buscando de hoy 1800 a mañana 800 necesitas dos intervalos; tu código JQL está buscando el día **d** de 800 a 1800 y el día **d-1** de 800 a 1800, no se parece en nada a lo que dices en tu comentario

Comment: Lo que me refieron es deseo saber los ticket que se crean en el lapso de hoy a las 18:00 pm  y como hora limite mañana a las 8:00 am

Comment: @ludvingodoy Por eso. Y en tu JQL buscas lo que está, digamos, ayer feb10 de 800 a 1800 Y lo de hoy feb11 de 800 y 1800. Entiendes lo que te estoy diciendo??? Si yo le digo a JQL (como te dije en la respuesta) que busque del final de feb10 al comienzo de feb11, es UN intervalo. Por favor, aclara EN la pregunta el intervalo y revisa si el JQL que pusiste trae eso o qué estás intentando realmente. Es más, como tienes `created > xx 800 AND created < xx 1800 OR created > yy 800 AND created < yy 1800`, las cuatro condiciones se están evaluando lógicamente al tiempo y eso tampoco hace lo que dices.

Comment: Cual seria tu solucion entonces.?

Comment: Lee lo que te he dicho en la respuesta y en los comentarios. Revisa y aclara tu pregunta. Tú eres el único que nos puede decir qué es lo que necesitas....